# Magento2 - Extra slash in thumbnail path shows broken images in file upload

Tags: magento2.3, backend, s3

I'm using `Magento2.3.3`.

I'm attempting to switch my images to `S3` and I have updated my media URL to my `amazon s3` bucket. The images are there and browsing the front-end works and correctly loads the images.

However, the `Upload Image` page on the `backend` (which comes up when managing block content) serves the thumbnail with an added slash between the media URL and the path, giving me a page full of broken images.

I can see from our live server that it is doing it there, too, but when it shows as a path divider (`mydomain.com/pub/media//file/name.jpg`) it seems to resolve just fine, but as a URL separator (https://mys3.amazonsaws.com//file/name.jpg) the image shows broken URL.

Does anyone know how I could fix this backend page to correctly load the thumbnail image `URL`?